# How does Pearson's cumulative test statistic approach Chi-squared distribution?

Tags: chi-squared-test, chi-squared-distribution

From Wikipedia,
$ \sum_1^k{Z_i^2}$ is Chi-squared distributed($Z_i$ is a standard normal random variable)

Also, it is followed by that Pearson's cumulative test statistic $ \sum_1^n{(O_i-E_i)^2 \over E_i}$ approaches to Chi-squared distribution.
($O_{i}$ = the number of observations of type $i$, $E_{i}$ = the expected (theoretical) frequency of type $i$)

I have been searching for the proof that $ \sum_1^n{(O_i-E_i)^2 \over E_i}$ approaches to $ \sum_1^k{Z_i^2}$, but I could not find it anywhere.

Is there anyone to show the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a binomial case. The size of observations is $n$ with probabilities $p$ and $q$ for types 1 and 2, respectively. Expected values are $np=E_1$ and $nq=E_2$ for type 1 and 2. Real observations are $O_1$ and $O_2$ for type 1 and 2. Then Pearson's chi-square statistic is

$X^2=\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-E_1)^2}{E_1} + \frac{(O_2-E_2)^2}{E_2}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-E_1)^2E_2+(O_2-E_2)^2E_1}{E_1E_2}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-E_1)^2q+(O_2-E_2)^2p}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-E_1)^2(1-p)+(O_2-E_2)^2p}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{-(O_1-E_1)^2p+(O_2-E_2)^2p+(O_1-E_1)^2}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{p \{(O_2-E_2)^2-(O_1-E_1)^2\}+(O_1-E_1)^2}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{p \{(O_2-E_2)-(O_1-E_1)(O_2-E_2)+(O_1-E_1)\}+(O_1-E_1)^2}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{p \{(O_2-E_2)-(O_1-E_1)\}(n-n)+(O_1-E_1)^2}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-E_1)^2}{npq}$

$\quad\ = \frac{(O_1-np)^2}{npq}$

This is the standardized and squared random variable from the binomial distribution.